# Finding the average centroid of all possible triangles given (x,y) coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, csv, math, geometry

I have a csv file of numerous (x,y) coordinates in the first quadrant. I want to find three things:

1. All possible triangles that can be created from the points
2. The centroids of all of the possible triangles that can be created from
   the points
3. The average of all possible centroids

I am using the code below for step 1:

```
def det(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return (x1 * (y2 - y3) - y1 *
            (x2 - x3) + 1 * (x2 *
                             y3 - y2 * x3))
def countPoints(Point, n):
    result = 0 
       for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                if (det(Point[i][0], Point[i][1],
                        Point[j][0], Point[j][1],
                        Point[k][0], Point[k][1])):
                    result = result + 1
    return result
Point = [[0, 0], [1, 1],
         [2, 0], [2, 2]]
n = len(Point)
print(countPoints(Point, n))
```

Now I am having trouble finding the coordinates of the number of possible triangles. Ex: If there are 3 possible triangles, I want to know their 3 vertex coordinates.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: You should use a list and add sets of three points to the list whenever they can create a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

To find all possible triangles that can be created from the set of points, `P`, you can try every possible set of 3 points from `P`. However, keep in mind that three points can create a triangle *if and only if they are not collinear*, meaning that they can't lie on the same line. This gives an `O(N^3)` algorithm for step number one.

The centroid of a triangle is defined as the intersection of all its medians, which seems like it would require processing the intersection point of three lines, which would be very tedious. However, if you simplify all the math, you'll find that the centroid of a triangle with coordinates `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), and (x3, y3)` is actually equal to `((x1+x2+x3)/3, (y1+y2+y3)/3)`. In other words, given a triangle, you can calculate its centroid in constant time.

For (#3), you can simply store all the centroids from the previous step in a list, and find the average by using the arithmetic mean formula:

The *arithmetic mean* of a set of numbers is equal to the cumulative sum of all the elements in that set divided by the number of elements in that set. The average of all the centroids can be calculated by summing all the x-values and dividing it by the number of centroids, and vice versa for the y-coordinates.